# Sending CURL/MQTT from chrome URL bar

Tags: google-chrome, curl, mqtt

Basically I have a script on a server that runs on a MQTT/CURL signal. Once either the MQTT or CURL gets called It starts/runs the script on the server and from there transfer the data to other machines. Why I want this to be run from Chrome (or any other browser) is because I would like to use a QR scanner to scan a QR code which holds the URL(mqtt or curl) and that this then gets run from the internal browser on the device. I know that there are apps and extensions for this, but I really need to get it as "thin client" as possible due to the large amount of devices that needs to be able to send the signal. Downloading an app for each device would defeat the purpose.

So my question really is if this is possible? Can Chrome send mqtt/curl from the url/address bar. I can't seem to find any information on this (maybe because it doesn't work? :D) HTTP post wont do unfortunately.

EDIT: If it doesn't work I have an idea to curl post from the console, but then my question is how would an url that opens console and inserts certain information look like? In other words I want an URL to include in my QR picture that opens Chrome (because it's a link) opens console and writes data like 101011101 (I can do the ENTER manually)

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, no Chrome can not in a single externally triggered action send a MQTT message. <sup>*</sup>

Curl is just a command line HTTP client it can send any HTTP request possible by the spec, so without LOT more detail about what exactly you are using it for the next part of this answer has to be a bit of a guess.

If you scan a QR code containing a HTTP URL then this will most likely be passed to the built in browser on the device (or a WebView in the barcode scanner application). This URL will opened using a HTTP GET request (you can not change the HTTP verb, it will always be a GET).

You can encode variables into the URLs query string by appending them to the end of the URL e.g.

```
http://www.example.com?foo=bar
```

Would send a variable named `foo` with a value of `bar` and as long as you have room in the data you store in the QR code you can add as many of these as you want.

<sup>*</sup> Chrome could be passed a URL to a page that loads the Paho Javascript MQTT library that then sends a message via MQTT over Websockets if the broker supports it, but if you are going to do that you might as well have what ever HTTP server that you load the page from send the message.